# Is thuis a good vba code for correct file name of are three vetter ways?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a filename with data from a cell. Certain characters cannot appear in a filename. This macro sometimes does not work correctly. Does anyone know if I can do this differently / better?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$1":    Target.Value = CorrectFileName(Target.Value)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function CorrectFileName(ByRef Waarde As String) As String
    Dim Tekens As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Tekens = "/\:@*?""""<>|{}[]"
    For i = 1 To Len(Tekens)
        Waarde = Replace(Waarde, Mid(Tekens, i, 1), "_")
    Next i
    CorrectFileName = Waarde
End Function
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is very opinion based and should better be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should provide details concerning the circumstances in which it doesn't work and specification to describe precisely what the code should be doing if that is your concern. "Sometimes does not work correctly" suggests this would be poorly suited to code-review: be sure to check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you do consider posting there to make sure your question is on topic, which as a minimum requires complete and working code along with an explanation of what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes in there twice, you can kick that out. Should not lead to wrong results, but certainly can be improved.

The changed range can be more than just one cell. If These cells do contain A1, your script won't fix the filename. In that somewhat ugly select case in your Sub, use Target.Cells(1,1).Address to fix.